# Creating div in vue for loop

Tags: vue.js, v-for, minesweeper

I'd like to do v-for loop for creating a div. I'm doing a minesweeper game and here is my code :

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="square"
    v-for="(square, index) in squares"
    :id="index"
    :key="index"
    :class="squares[index]"
    @click="clicked(square, index)"
    >
    </div>
</div>
```

'Squares' in this code is an array with shuffled classes 'bomb' or 'empty'. I know that it's wrong because after I click on random square I get only this class from te 'squares' array. What should be there instead of this 'squares' array in v-for. I want to get whole  with classes, attributes etc. because later I have to use 'classList' 'contains' etc.

Sorry, maybe I'm completly wrong and talking bullshit, but I started with vue 3 weeks ago.

Here is the method clicked which I want to use

```
clicked(square) {
        
    if(this.isGameOver) return;
    if(square.classList.contains('chechked') || square.classList.contains('flag')) return
    if(square.classList.contains('bomb')) {
        this.gameOver(square);
    } else {
        let total = square.getAttribute('data');

        if(total != 0) {
            square.classList.add('checked');
            square.innerHTML = total;
            return
        }
    }
    square.classList.add('checked');
}
```

Comment: When you click, you are calling the method "Clicked" with two arguments, the first is an object (most likely) that you iterating from squares, the second an integer (the index). If inside your method clicked yo put a console log, you'll see both passed elements

Comment: so what to change to get div, because now i can't use classList.contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access the div element but you are passing the object in the method and you are asking for classList into the object (that does not have it). You should query the element instead.

Change the @click handler in your component to:

```
    @click="clicked"
```

and your method to:

```
clicked(event) {

        let square = event.target;
        console.log(square);
        console.log(square.classList);
        ...
```